# Eclipse shows uppercase HTML tags for code completion when editing JSF HTML5 files

Tags: eclipse, html, jsf, editor

I have a problem when editing HTML5 source files of a JSF application in Eclipse (tried it in Luna and Mars). In my application these files have the extension .xhtml.

The code completion of HTML tags changes between uppercase and lowercase  depending on how the document is classified. This is what I found out:

- When using a HTML5 doctype and the ending .html (lowercase)
- When using a HTML5 doctype and the ending .xhtml (uppercase)
- When using a XHTML Transitional doctype and the ending .xhtml (lowercase)

I tried several settings concerning file association and content type. Of course I activated the lowercase setting of the HTML editor settings. Without success.

What I want is lowercase tags, HTML5 doctype and a .xhtml file extension. Is that possible?

By the way it is a project under the control of m2e with the m2e JavaEE configuration helpers enabled. But the above effect happens in non m2e projects, too.

I did some more tests:

- I started a new workspace with default settings.
- I created a new dynamic web project.
- I added a HTML index.html file.
- Content assist shows lowercase tags.
- I renamed the file to index.xhtml.
- Content assist shows uppercase tags.

File assosiation setting .xhtml is locked to Facelet composite component and the default editor is the HTML editor.

File assosiation setting .html is locked to HTML and the default editor is the HTML editor.

In the meanwhile I also tried a clean install of 4.4.2 platform binary with just the WTP components integrated - same result.

I think it's a bug and created a bug report with #465878 ([Eclipse Bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=465878)). What's your opinion?

Thanks for your help.

Dieter

Comment: After adjusting the editor settings (window > preferences > web > HTML files > editor), try performing a project clean, restart Eclipse and possibly the computer.

Comment: You mean, you have set `<!DOCTYPE html>` in the xhtml file? I've tried that, it is still lower case for my Eclipse. But you don't need to set the doctype for all of your XHTML files, if you use ui:composition with a template, as in that case you would only need the correct doctype in the template.

Comment: Correct. This is the way I'm working now. Use the HTML5 doctype for the template and the XHTML doctype for the page instances.